# Using datetime2 with Informatica

Tags: sql-server, datetime, informatica

I have the requirement for dates that predate 1753, the minimum for datetime on SQL Server. DB-side, the solution is clear: change to datetime2 format. But it seems Informatica still treats the column as datetime. I suppose datetime2 is not supported. Is there any workaround that could enable me to insert pr-1753 dates in a datetime2 column?

Informatica version is 9.1.0, SQL Server 2008

Comment: If relevant, it appears that `Datetime2` support is [introduced in  9.5](https://community.informatica.com/docs/DOC-3950)

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to a newer version of Informatica won't help or isn't an option, then you've got limited options. One option is to CONVERT the datetime2 to a suitable VARCHAR representation from the SQL Server side and then feed *that* to Informatica and let the implict casting of the value back to a suitable DATETIME do the hard work for you.

You'll need to make sure you are *very* careful with this though - if you end up migrating text dates such as 02/03/2015 02:33 etc - then there's a chance that if regional settings differ between databases or servers, you could import that as either 2nd of March or 3rd of Feb. It's best to use culture-invariant date formats, such as yyyy-mm-dd - that way it's always unambiguous.

-Steve

Comment: The problem is _writing_ the dates, not reading. Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a SQL override for targets...

Comment: Use a VIEW that accepts  the VARCHAR and then remap to the target table with an INSTEAD of trigger. That way you can perform whatever other remapping you want. 

Another option might be to use a stored procedure as the destination, with the parameter as a VARCHAR instead.